# WSO2 : how to download products in a Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, wso2

I would like to download your products(Esb 4.8.1 , Am 1.9.0 , IS(pp) 5.0.0) using a Dockerfile. However there are no direct download links on the website( it seems you would prefer to gather my personal information instead - again) , before I download it.

This seems to go against what appears on the WSO2 website :

> 100% Open Source
>
> No other company offers you a *truly* free and comprehensive middleware
>   stack that you can download full production-ready versions. This gives
>   you *unlimited* opportunity to *explore* and *experiment* with our platform
>   with no licensing costs. No Tricks. No hidden agendas....

I've tried :

```
wget http://product-dist.wso2.com/products/enterprise-service-bus/4.8.1/wso2esb-4.8.1.zip
```

- forbidden

I can get the old(er) versions with

```
 http://dist.wso2.org/maven2/org/wso2/esb/wso2esb/4.8.0/wso2esb-4.8.0.zip
```

Please advise.

EDIT :

The correct url to download for example ESB-4.8.1 (credit to Abimaran Kugathasan) :

```
wget -P /opt --user-agent="testuser" --referer="http://connect.wso2.com/wso2/getform/reg/new_product_download"  http://product-dist.wso2.com/products/enterprise-service-bus/4.8.1/wso2esb-4.8.1.zip
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like following

```
wget --user-agent="testuser" --referer="http://connect.wso2.com/wso2/getform/reg/new_product_download"  http://product-dist.wso2.com/products/enterprise-service-bus/4.8.1/wso2esb-4.8.1.zip
```

And, for your information, WSO2 ESB 4.9.0, APIM (AM) 1.9.1 were released recently. You better use latest versions.

Comment: Thanks  , but you gave the wrong repo link , see above edit for correct uri

Comment: Yes, I used the old link with new version. :)